# ROW_NUMBER() issue in hive

Tags: hive, indexoutofboundsexception, row-number

I am trying to use ROW_NUMBER() function in hive (version 0.13). I am partitioning by a unique number, however ordering is happening based on transaction amount and customer name.

Although this piece of code works for non-unique condition (where unique key, ordering key is same) upto 4k rows, in some cases, I am getting 162k rows with the same non-unique condition. I getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. Although I can filter out all these cases, since all these numbers are for name having a blank string value, that would not solve the purpose of business rule implementation.

How can I handle this in the code, other than filtering out.

This is the piece of code I am using :

```
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE_NUMBER ORDER BY CREDIT_AMT DESC, NAME ASC) AS CREDIT_PARTY_NO
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE_NUMBER ORDER BY DEBIT_AMT DESC,  NAME ASC) AS DEBIT_PARTY_NO
```

A quick search over how much count I am generating:

```
COUNT : 162344  CREDIT_AMT : 0  DEBIT_AMT : 2070596 NAME : BLANK    case_number:12345*************
```

Comment: You should edit your question with the query you are using and an example of the results you are getting (and perhaps the data used to generate those results).  `ROW_NUMBER()` doesn't have any argument that is described as a "condition", so it is rather unclear what you are trying to explain.

Comment: Just added the code and count I am getting for the condition passed. Is it because of the huge count?

Comment: Your question simply makes no sense.  If you are *partitioning* by a unique number, then `row_number()` will always return 1.